# Divide two "Calculated Values" within Spofire Graphical Table

Tags: spotfire

I have a spotfire question. Is it possible to divide two "calculated value" columns in a "graphical table".

I have a Count([Type]) calculated value. I then limit the data within the second calculated value to arrive at a different number of Count[Type].

I would like to divide the two in a third calculated value column.

ie.

Calculated value column 1:

Count([Type]) = 100 (NOT LIMITED)

Calculated value column 2:

Count([Type]) = 50 (Limited to [Type]="Good")

Now I would like to say 50/100 = 0.5 in the third calculated value column.

If it is possible to do this all within one calculated column value that is even better. Graphical Tables do not let you have if statements in the custom expression, the only way is to limit data. So I am struggling, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphical tables do allow `IF()` in custom expressions. In order to accomplish this you are going to have to move your logic away from the **Limit Data Using Expressions** and into your expression directly. Here should be your three Axes expressions:

- `Count([Type])`
- `Count(If([Type]="Good",[Type]))`
- `Count(If([Type]="Good",[Type])) / Count([Type])`

**Data Set**

```
+----+------+
| ID | Type |
+----+------+
|  1 | Good |
|  1 | Good |
|  1 | Good |
|  1 | Good |
|  1 | Good |
|  1 | Bad  |
|  1 | Bad  |
|  1 | Bad  |
|  1 | Bad  |
|  2 | Good |
|  2 | Good |
|  2 | Good |
|  2 | Good |
|  2 | Bad  |
|  2 | Bad  |
|  2 | Bad  |
|  2 | Bad  |
+----+------+
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: THANKS!!!! its always so easy.... you have to nest the if within a count! didnt think of that.. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem @brandog I figured you tried it the other way around it and gave you an error about "it must be an aggregate function" or something similar.  Cheers mate.